# How to display string response from db as one by one in Android? 

Tags: android, soap, android-view

I am new developer in android. I am working with soap object in my application for communicate with the .net db services.I am getting response as strings from DB server. But my intention is when I get a string from db server as response then imediatly view as text view similarly I am getting images encoded string.how to get response imedialty as view. I have written code as follows:

```
String xml="<spGetUserMessages><SearchLocation></SearchLocation><LoginUserID>"+Userid+"</LoginUserID></spGetUserMessages>";
```

I am sending request as XML to db server

The response from db server is in list:

```
 List<MessageClass> response=new ParseXml().getUserMessages(new Generic().getMessages(xml));

  String messages=new String[response.size()];

  for(int i=0;i<response.size();i++)
         {

           //the response values are saved in messages array
             messages[i]=response.get(i).getmessage();

               }
```

I have written a **base adapter** class in that class we have a method as getView I have implemented as follows:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;


    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);



     TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
     ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

     Log.v("rrrrrrrrrr", "rrrrrrrr"+messages[position]);

     text.setText(messages[position]);
    }
```

From the above code I am displaying all messages at a time. But in this situation the response is taking time then I am getting blank screen. Here my intention is when I get a string response then I will view that string as text view next time next similarly untill reposnse size has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is display the Listview without waiting for response and from background thread add the responses to `messages` and call

```
mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

This is concept of `LazyLoading` and I hope it should work

**Update**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
```

Comment: hey ingsaurabh, i have created LazyLoading mAdater object ant called as mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); but it is not applicable to view imedialty,when i get one message as string.plzzz could u give good solution on it

Comment: Updated the answer check that

Comment: hey no difference same thing no effect

Answer (score 1):

use the AsyncTask class to work in background process like this way

```
private String messages[];
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

     public void doInBackground(Void... arg){

      List<MessageClass> response=new ParseXml().getUserMessages(new Generic().getMessages(xml));

        messages=new String[response.size()];

       for(int i=0;i<response.size();i++){
       //the response values are saved in messages array
         messages[i]=response.get(i).getmessage();

        } 
     }

     public void postExecute(Void result){
           // here you initialize the listview so the getview() method will call after fetching the response and store into the array.
     }
}
```

Comment: hey Pratik i am getting messages from back ground but not apply to view.if i gets a response as "hai" then imediatly i would like to view that hai.plzzz give good solution on it